# Odometry with Cartographer

Tags: odometry, cartographer, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04.

I am working on getting the navigation stack working and I am stuck with the Odometry input. I am currently working with an Ouster LIDAR alongside with an IMU. I have set up SLAM using cartographer, which will give me the map input into the navigation stack.

I was wondering if their is a way to obtain Odometry message from Cartographer itself or build it from the sensors that I am currently using. I am fairly new to ROS and I do not know where to start.

Thanks for any help/information you can provide.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311263/odometry-with-cartographer/) by [LunarJeff](https://answers.ros.org/users/36996/lunarjeff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can start with the [ROS Navigation Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials). More specifically, the [Publishing Odometry Information over ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom) tutorial explains how to publish odometry messages for a predefined movement. Normally you would use your sensors (e.g. encoders + imu) to determine the odometry.

---

Originally posted by [Wilco Bonestroo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30578/wilco-bonestroo/) with karma: 159 on 2018-12-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LunarJeff](https://answers.ros.org/users/36996/lunarjeff/) on 2018-12-21**:
I saw the odometry tutorial on odometry, my problem is that I only have an IMU and no encoders. Is there a way to obtain odometry just from the IMU itself or in combination with the LIDAR?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2018-12-21**:
Yes, you can use laser scans to match between frames and then back out the estimated change in position. There may be some packages that do this for you - but none come to mind at this moment.

**Comment by [Wilco Bonestroo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30578/wilco-bonestroo/) on 2018-12-23**:
[Robot_localization](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/index.html) can be used for state estimation based any number of sensors. I don't know if you can use it without encoders.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can set cartographer to publish odometry, or else you can generate odometry using some other algorithms. But you cannot do both at the same time.

You may need to know that odometry which provided by wheel encoder is odom->base_link, map->odom is the drift error and provided by mapping process.

reference: https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html

If you only want to use cartographer with your lidar and IMU, and do not want to use a supplementary odometry, set use_odometry to false, and published frame should be base_footprint or base_link. Because a mapping procedure normally publish tf from map to odom, which indicates the drift error. The drift error plus a raw odometry we will have the pose of base_link w.r.t. map.

Then you can configure whether you want cartographer provide the odom frame. set provide_odom_frame to false the mapping process will give you base_link to map directly, however as a convention, better set provide the odom frame to true and the odom frame will be published. Then you can have the odom info from cartographer.

```
  map_frame = "map",
  tracking_frame = "IMU_link",

  use_odometry = false,
  published_frame = "base_footprint",

  provide_odom_frame = true,
  odom_frame = "odom",
```

As you have already disabled odometry, you could set imu to true, this gives better SLAM result.

```
  TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.use_imu_data = true
```

Another case is that you can use some other method to generate odom instead of cartographer. For example if you use velodyne you can try https://github.com/laboshinl/loam_velodyne, or rplidar you can try https://github.com/MAPIRlab/rf2o_laser_odometry

if you have wheel encoder, it is similar configuration. if you set provide odom frame to true, cartographer node wont die but the odom frame will oscillating because tf to odom is broadcasted by two nodes. In this case,  odom_frame has no use.

Even if you set imu to true, it will not adjust the perception according to imu readings.  Sensor readings are attached to base_link which is provided by odom->base_link which is provided by odometry.

```
  map_frame = "map",
  tracking_frame = "base_footprint",

  use_odometry = true,
  published_frame = "odom",

  provide_odom_frame = false,
  odom_frame = "odom",
```

(Some conclusion is not fully tested but I think it will be.)

If you are interested in the full code, I am busy updating an racecar project recently. you could check this out: https://github.com/tianbot/tianracer

---

Originally posted by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) with karma: 710 on 2018-12-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jackchin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26479/jackchin/) on 2019-12-12**:
thanks a lot !

**Comment by [rjosodtssp](https://answers.ros.org/users/38070/rjosodtssp/) on 2020-07-15**:
when use_odometry = false, trancking_frame = imu,   cartographer  doesn't  work

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2020-07-15**:
Maybe you can check whether your IMU output is correct. I remember that cartographer requires the angular velocity. you could open a new question with a detailed description